# Calcular media aritmética con valores aleatorios PHP7

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, loops

Tengo que hacer un bucle while para calcular la media aritmética de 15 números aleatorios.

No me da error, pero se queda cargando continuamente:

```
<?php
//Función para números aleatorios
function gennum (){
    while ($i <= 15) {
        $i = 0;
        //Aqui intento que me genere 15 números aleatorios y los sumo
        $suma = rand(0, 100)+$i;
        $i++;
    }
    return $suma;

    //Aquí quiero que me haga la media aritmética de los 15 números generados
    $media = $suma / 15;
    echo "La media aritmética es $media";
}
$func = gennum();
echo $func;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está que inicias de nuevo la variable `$i` cada vuelta y estas devolviendo la `$suma` antes que hagas la `$media`:

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cef7c15db1f4a19c2640fad4fc316ea8b93e7cfb)**

```
//Función para números aleatorios
function gennum (){

    // Poner fuera del while y iniciar con 1 para que sean 15 vueltas 
    $i    = 1; 

    // Iniciar la suma 
    $suma = 0;       

    while ($i <= 15) {            
        $suma += rand(0, 100);
        $i++;
    }

    $media = $suma / 15;
    return "La media aritmética es $media";
}

$func = gennum();
echo $func;
```

**EDIT:**
Según @Mariano he cambiado el código para que calcule la media, correctamente.

Comment: .y otra cosa que recién veo: son 16 ciclos, y se divide por 15

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora lo pruebo, lo de las vueltas no me había fijado... qué hace +=?

Comment: @ras212 `$variable += 31;` es lo mismo que `$variable = $variable + 31;`

Comment: @ras212 - Cada vuelta se suma a la variable `$suma` a la suma anterior => `vuelta 1: 0 + 12 | vuelta 2: 12 + 34 | vuelta 3: 46 + 33 | ..........`

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por todo.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres usar *Php7*, una nueva característica del mismo, es que puedes indicar el tipo de valor que retorna una función.

http://php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php

Yo lo haría así:

```
function gennum ():int
{
  $i = 1; 

  $suma = 0;

  while ( $i <= 15)
  {
    $suma += rand(0, 100);
    $i++;
  }

  $suma /= 15; 

  return $suma;
}

$resultado = gennum ();
echo "Resultado: $resultado";
```